# PHP How to count same words in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, count

I have this result inside my foreach loop:

```
Tonsilitis
Tonsilitis
Laryngitis
Rhinosinusitis Akut
Rhinosinusitis Akut
Rhinosinusitis Akut
Common Cold
Common Cold
Common Cold
Rhinitis Alergi
```

This is my script:

```
foreach ($results as $data) :
   $final = $data->nama_diagnosis . '<br>';
   echo $final;
endforeach;
```

My question is, how can i count the same word in my loop or outside the loop. Can i do that? give me the solution please. As a result i want to count them like this:

```
Tonsilitis = 2
Laryngitis = 1
Rhinosinusitis Akut = 3
Common Cold = 3
Rhinitis Alergi = 1
```

Or maybe i can filter the same word so i get only the most words, like Rhinosinusitis Akut and Common Cold. Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In foreach loop save words and their count into array, then make another loop and write the amounts.

```
<?php

$results = array(
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Tonsilitis'),
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Tonsilitis'),
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Laryngitis'),
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Rhinosinusitis Akut'),
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Rhinosinusitis Akut'),
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Rhinosinusitis Akut'),
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Common Cold'),
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Common Cold'),
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Common Cold'),
    array('nama_diagnosis' => 'Rhinitis Alergi')
);

$res = array();
foreach ($results as $words) {  // changed $word to $words
    foreach ($words as $word) { // this foreach added
        if (isset($res[$word])) {
            $res[$word] += 1;
        } else {
            $res[$word] = 1;
        }
    } // end of nested foreach which was added
}

foreach ($res as $word => $count) {
    echo $word . ' (' . $count . ')<br>';
}

/*
    output:

    Tonsilitis (2)
    Laryngitis (1)
    Rhinosinusitis Akut (3)
    Common Cold (3)
    Rhinitis Alergi (1)
*/

?>
```

Comment: This is my array.. can i convert it?

Array ( [0] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Tonsilitis ) [1] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Tonsilitis ) [2] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Laryngitis ) [3] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Rhinosinusitis Akut ) [4] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Rhinosinusitis Akut ) [5] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Rhinosinusitis Akut ) [6] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Common Cold ) [7] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Common Cold ) [8] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Common Cold ) [9] => Array ( [nama_diagnosis] => Rhinitis Alergi ) ) Tonsilitis (2)

Comment: @RK26: I've updated my answer, nested `foreach` was added (and in the first one I've changed `$word` to `$words` - `foreach ($results as $words) {...}`).

Comment: Can i only show one word with the most count? is it possible?

Comment: @RK26: See the `sort` function.

Comment: When i use rsort($res), the order is correct, but the words become a number aswell

Comment: Done, i use usort and its working, but how can i select only first array and remove the rest, because i want to show only one word with the most count.

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this, iterating through array with `foreach` loop and using a ternary operator with `isset` to safely assign and increment each occurrence:

```
$count = array();
foreach ($results as $result)
    isset($count[$data]) ? $count[$data]++ : $count[$data] = 1;
```

#### [Example](https://eval.in/241310)

Comment: It seems that `$data` is an object in OP's loop and has to use: `$data->nama_diagnosis` but other then that, very nice trick with the isset combined with the ternary operator! +1

Comment: @Rizier123 : It was kinda odd to me that [this approach](https://eval.in/241313) works too.

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($results as $data) :
   $final = $data->nama_diagnosis . '<br>';
   if (array_key_exists($data->nama_diagnosis, $counts)) {
        $counts[$data->nama_diagnosis] += 1;
   } else {
        $count[$data->nama_diagnosis] = 1;
   }
endforeach;

foreach ($counts as $key => $val) { 
    echo $key.' = '.$val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $results = array("Tonsilitis", "Tonsilitis", "Laryngitis", "Rhinosinusitis Akut", "Rhinosinusitis Akut", "Rhinosinusitis Akut", "Common Cold", "Common Cold", "Common Cold", "Rhinitis Alergi");
    $counter = array();


    foreach ($results as $data):
        if(in_array($data->nama_diagnosis, array_flip($counter)))
            $counter[$data->nama_diagnosis]++;
        else
            $counter[$data->nama_diagnosis] = 1;
    endforeach;

    foreach ($counter as $key => $data)
       echo $key . " = " . $data . "<br />"; 

?>
```

Output:

```
Tonsilitis = 2
Laryngitis = 1
Rhinosinusitis Akut = 3
Common Cold = 3
Rhinitis Alergi = 1
```